# UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation ignored on a UITextField with secure text entry

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uitextfield, uikeyboard

I've got a UITextField that represents a numeric password. I need to set the keyboard type to UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation and secureTextEntry at the same time.

If I set to Yes the secureTextEntry, the textField displays a Default Keyboard even if I had  set UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation to the textField keyboard type.

By the other hand, if I set the keyboard type to UIKeyboardTypeNumberPad it works fine, but I have no done/return key to dismiss that keyboard. =S

is there a solution or a workaround for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I don't know it is a bug or not...

I changed the code from

XXX.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation

XXX.secureTextEntry = YES

to

XXX.secureTextEntry = YES

XXX.KeyboardType = UIKeyboardTypeNumbersAndPunctuation

Then, it works...